# What steps can I take if SE is no longer accepting answers from my account?

Tags: support, answers

I have answered [two questions](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/9114/arunabh-bhattacharya?tab=answers) so far. But Music Fans SE [is not accepting any more answers from my account](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans). So, I need to improve my existing answers, so that I can answer more questions. So, how can I improve my existing answers?

- [Measure numbers proper name](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10651/measure-numbers-proper-name/10657#10657), and
- [Who wrote this arrangement of Moonlight Sonata for the electric guitar?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10659/who-wrote-this-arrangement-of-moonlight-sonata-for-the-electric-guitar/10662#10662)

Both my answers are currently downvoted to -2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system tries to limit someone who has a negative answer record as they are typically generating low quality answers that need attention. You only have 4 answers, but they are only on two questions which shows that you need a little more guidance on how answers work on the site. Here are some things to keep in mind when answering question.

- Unless you have a really good reason, please only post one answer per question. There are cases where it's valid to post more than one, but those are rare and the answers posted typically have different content/approaches.
- Read the other answers and see what you are adding. If your answer is covered by the other answers, just upvote them.
- Read comments on your answer. One answer already has several comments indicating issues.
- If your answer is a link add context and explain a little more in depth. For example every other answer on the rehearsal mark question explained more about them in general and you just provided a definition. While a good start, it's not all the way to a full answer yet.
- Read the [how to answer section of the FAQ](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)